# If there is $B \subset A$ with $\mu(B)=\mu^{\ast}(A)$ then $A$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset E$ such that $\mu^{\ast}(A)<+\infty$, How can I prove that If there is $B \subset A$ with $\mu(B)=\mu^{\ast}(A)$ then $A$ is measurable.

Is it true if $\mu(A)=+\infty$?

I don't know how attack this problem, could someone help me with this, please.

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Something wrong with your hypothesis. Writing $\mu(A)$ you assume measurability of $A$. What a measure is $\mu$? It looks to be constructed from an outer measure via Caratheodory's Theorem. If yes, this measure is complete. Is $B$ measurable?

Comment: Do you mean $\mu(E) < +\infty$?  If you're given that $\mu(A) < +\infty$, then $A$ is automatically measurable.  I'm assuming your two mentions of $\mu(A)$ should instead be $\mu(E)$ since otherwise I don't see the significance of $E$ at all here.

Comment: sorry is $\mu^{\ast}(A)<+\infty$

Comment: @Knight You want to show if $A$ is $\mu^*$-measurable?

Comment: yes I am studying Lebesgue measure

Comment: IF the outer measure of A is finite and if there is a subset of A with his measure equals to the outer measure of A then A is measurable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $A$ be such that $\mu^*(A) < \infty$ and let $B \subset A$ be a measurable set such that $\mu(B) = \mu^*(A).$ Then $$\mu^*(A \setminus B) = \mu^*(A) - \mu^*(B) = 0.$$

Notice that for the previous equalities to be true we need the assumption $\mu^*(A) < \infty$. This is in general not true otherwise, indeed one can consider $A = \mathbb{R}$ and $B = (0,\infty)$. Then $\mu(A) = \mu(B) = \infty$, but clearly $$\mu(A \setminus B) = \mu((-\infty,0)) = \infty.$$

> This shows that $A \setminus B$ is measurable since by the Caratheodory condition sets of outer measure $0$ are measurable. To conclude the argument it is enough to notice that $A$ belongs to the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets since it can be written as the union of two measurable sets: $$A = B \cup (A \setminus B).$$

The result is not true in general if $\mu^*(A) = \infty$. Indeed, let $C \subset (-1,0)$ be a *non*-measurable set and consider $B = (0,\infty)$ and $A = B \cup C$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested already, first show $\mu^*(A \cap B^c) = 0$ if $\mu^*(A) < \infty$.

Next, using this result, you can show directly that $\mu^*(T \cap A)=\mu^*(T \cap B)$ and $\mu^*(T \cap A^c) = \mu^*(T \cap B^c)$ for all $T \subset \Omega$. This implies by measurability of $B$ that
\begin{equation}
\mu^*(T \cap A) + \mu^*(T \cap A^c) = \mu^*(T \cap B) + \mu^*(T \cap B^c) = \mu^*(T) .
\end{equation}
Hence, $A$ is measurable.

To prove the claims that $\mu^*(T \cap A)=\mu^*(T \cap B)$ and $\mu^*(T \cap A^c) = \mu^*(T \cap B^c)$ for all $T \subset \Omega$, note that from $B \subset A$ and monotonicity of $\mu^*$ it follows that
\begin{equation}
\mu^*(T \cap A) = \mu^*(T \cap A \cap B) + \mu^*(T \cap A \cap B^c) = \mu^*(T \cap B) + 0 .
\end{equation}
Note that we have $\mu^*(T \cap A \cap B^c) = 0$ by monotonicity. 
Moreover, $\mu^*(T \cap A^c) \leq \mu^*(T \cap B^c)$ by monotonicity and 
\begin{equation}
\mu^*(T \cap B^c) \leq \mu^*(T \cap B^c \cap A) + \mu^*(T \cap B^c \cap A^c) = 0 + \mu^*(T \cap A^c)
\end{equation}
by subadditivity. Hence, $\mu^*(T \cap A^c) = \mu^*(T \cap B^c)$, as claimed.

Comment: but this implies the measurability of T not A

Comment: Caratheodory's criterion states that $A$ is measurable iff $\mu^*(T) = mu^*(T \cap A) + mu^*(T \cap A^c)$ for all $T \subset \Omega$, as I have shown

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For the first part, note that $\mu(B)=\mu_*(B)=\mu^*(A)$. Conclude that $\mu^*(A\setminus B)=0$. For the second part, let $A'$ be your favourite non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ and consider $A=A'\cup (1,\infty)$.